# Using payable functions in the remix ide

Tags: solidity, remix, testnets, testing, payable

I created a simple solidity contract in the remix ide. I cannot figure out how to test the payable functions I created.

here is an example of a payable function:

```
function pay() payable {
}
```

here is a picture of a payable function buy() which does not accept ether or a value in remix

[image: here is a picture of a payable function buy() which does not accept ether or a value in remix]

how can i test payable functions on a test chain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is rather unintuitive on Remix, but there is a `value` input near the top of the panel (circled red). You can enter the value there before clicking on a function call. You'll need to do it for every call as the input field clears after a transaction.

[image: Screenshot of Remix IDE]

Comment: thank you! exactly what I was looking for... I even implemented a simple wallet to no avail! this info about the value field should be made clearer